# creating 4D lookup table

Tags: c, arrays, performance, lookup

I need to create fast 4D lookup table according to the following:
1- it will receive 4 input variables (u,v,i,j) each one range from 0 to 15
2- the lookup table returns a precalculated value of 8 bit 
how can I implement this 4D lookup table in very fast code in C Language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a 4-dimensional array on the stack.  16^4 bytes is a size that should fit on the stack on most platforms, otherwise make it static or global.  It gives the compiler full knowledge about the layout, it is a well known and commonly used language construct, it should optimize well:

```
  uint8_t lookup[16][16][16][16];   // global table about 64KB 


  int main(int, char **)
  {
       ...
```

Of course you can make one dimensional array `uint8_t lookup[16*16*16*16]` and multiply your values `lookup[u*16*16*16 + v*16*16 + i*16 + j]` but I massively doubt that you will be able to make this more performant than the 4-dim array (where the compiler does this kind of multiplication internally anyway)

Since you are asking about the initialization, here is an example of how to init a 4-dim array. for simplicity it is just `[4][4][4][4]`, so you have to increase that to 16 (16 blocks of 16 rows, of 16 series of 16 numbers.

```
uint8_t test[4][4][4][4]= {
       { // [0][x][y][z]
         { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
         { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
         { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
         { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }  },

       { // [1][x][y][z]
         { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, 
         { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, 
         { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, 
         { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }  },

       { // [2][x][y][z]
         { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, 
         { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, 
         { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, 
         { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }  },                  

       { // [3][x][y][z]
         { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, 
         { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, 
         { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, 
         { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 }  }  
};
```

Comment: What you mean by "full knowledge about the layout and dimensions so it can optimize it"

Comment: and how can I add it in the stack

Comment: " 16^4 bytes is a size that would still fit on the stack" How do you know what fits on his stack? Also, I don't think 4 dimensional arrays are a "commonly used language construct"

Comment: On the stack, just define it inside a function like any local variable.  With the comment about layout/dimension I mean, that this definition tells the compile exactly how you are going to access it.  There would be other (more dynamic ways to create such a table, where the compiler at compile time would know less about how the memory is going to be used, and hence could not optimize as well).

Comment: @cubic: Fixed sizes arrays are a commonly used very basic language construct and compilers will naturally have strategies how to handle them best.

Comment: please, I am not expert in C code can you give me smaal example on how to tell the compiler a comment about layout/dimension

Comment: @moursa: this definition above does it automatically (tell the compiler the layout/dimensions). you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: I mean, I need to declare the lookup function outside of the main program as an 4D array and put all values in this array(65536 values)